# Sphero AR Unity SDK for IOS

Tags: augmented-reality, sphero-api, sphero

I am currently trying to get the [Sphero AR SDK](https://github.com/orbotix/Sphero-AR-SDK) running. I tried it with a various combination of different Xcodes and Unitys and it keeps crashing at the splash screen. So my guess would be that the frameworks are outdated for the newer IOS versions (8.0+).

Is anyone able to run it or does a workaround exists to get it run? Or did anyone tried to combine the Sphere with another AR framework?

Cheers

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am looking to get the SDK running on iOS 11 but am afraid it is too dated.